# What means a *10 or ?1 in my terminal with Oh-My-Zsh and Powerlevel10k theme on MacOs?

Tags: macos, terminal

I have recently installed OhMyZsh, with Powerlevel10k theme. I know this is git related, but,
what means the *10 or the ?1 signs and numbers?

Thanks in advance.

[my terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv5uy.png)

I have installed szh, with oh my szh, then, installed Powerlevel10k theme, then trying to customize that i found that numbers on my terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*10` means there are 10 stashes in your repo. (`git stash list`)

`?1` means your working copy is dirty i.e. there are new, edited or deleted files in the repo (`git status`).

Here is Powerlevel10k reference for vcs: https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k#vcs-symbols